# How to search words from a column of one file in another file and print matching lines?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have two files. For example below:

File 1:

```
Polaromonas naphthalenivorans
uncultured bacterium
Leptothrix cholodnii
Clostridium clariflavum
Methylocystis parvus
Calditerrivibrio nitroreducens
```

File 2:

```
Polaromonas naphthalenivorans   143990  0   6   4   0   0
uncultured bacterium    43393   0   11174   285 0   0
Leptothrix cholodnii    26955   0   0   0   0   0
Clostridium clariflavum 2544    0   3   0   0   2
Met parvus  1603    131 0   0   0   197
Caldi nit   998 831 11  70  7   117
```

Desired output:

```
Polaromonas naphthalenivorans   143990  0   6   4   0   0
uncultured bacterium    43393   0   11174   285 0   0
Leptothrix cholodnii    26955   0   0   0   0   0
Clostridium clariflavum 2544    0   3   0   0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

[grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) has this functionality built-in:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2
```

means: look for the `F`ixed strings from `f`ile1 in file2 and report the matching lines from file2.

Comment: I am following command but  it is showing 0KB.                                 
grep -Ff file1.csv file2.csv >out.txt

Comment: then the exact string(s) from file1 are not present in file2. Perhaps there's whitespace at the beginning, middle, or end?

Comment: @JeffSchaller and Manoj Kumar, I smell a windows `file1` with extra `\r`. What is the `file -i `?

Comment: or `grep -q $'\x0D' file1.csv && echo carriage returns detected`

Comment: File 1 has one column and need to find matching words from file 2.

Comment: @Manoj, run `file -i File1.csv` or my grep example just above, and edit that into your Q, please.

Comment: grep -Ff file1 file2,  this command does not work?

Comment: @ManojKumar do you see our comments & questions above?

Comment: Yes, those input files does not have any whitespace at the beginning, middle, or end..the output generate with the following command but it is including mismatch data from file 2.csv.                     
        grep -vwFf file1 file2